# How to connect to 2 or more peripherals while receiving data from all at once using Core Bluetooth in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I have managed to connect, receive and display data from 1 BLE device.

However my app requires me to connect to 2 or more of these devices (they have different addresses).

I've read that it's possible to connect to multiple devices at once but I couldn't find a proper guide or implementation after extensive searching.

Do I need to assign 2 peripheral objects? Or have 2 delegates for peripheral?

I would really appreciate if someone could explain to me how to go about this.

Thank you for your time. :)

Comment: You just connect to the two peripherals. Both peripherals will have your class as your delegate. You need to keep an property reference (such as an array) for your connected peripherals so that you can determine which peripheral the delegate method has been called for (compare the peripheral passed to the delegate with your properties/array). Can you show what you have tried and where you have specific problems?

Comment: Hi @Paulw11 

Thanks for the reply.

http://pastebin.com/UyQ7CNTn

My code can be assessed in that link. I do have the addresses (UUID) of the devices. I do not understand how I can declare 2 peripherals however.. 

Thanks,
Vevek :)

Comment: Replace `self.connectingPeripheral` with an dictionary `[String:CBPeripheral]` so you can hold more than one connected peripheral reference. When you discover a new peripheral add it to the dictionary with `peripheral.Identifier.UUIDString` as the key

Comment: Hi @Paulw11 Thank you so much! It works :)

Comment: @Paulw11 - have you got a code example of how to do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53526621/scanning-ble-peripheral-and-connecting-to-it/53527093