# Scanning BLE peripheral and connecting to it

Tags: swift, xcode, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Fairly new to BLE and coding mobile apps in general. I've tried several demos and came across this https://github.com/RickRedSix/BLE4.0-iOS-Swift-Demo 
Problem is that it doesn't connect to my BLE device, so I assume it only scans for the BLE device creator had at the time so I always get the error "can only accept this command while in the powered on state". Is there any part in the code I need to change to make it scan another peripheral? Do I need to specify my device's UUID, MAC address, or other unique information somewhere?

Appreciate any help on this problem

Answer (score 3):

I had worked on an app about a year ago to scan and connect to BLE Devices. Posting code from that project. It might not work if u copy paste it exactly as it is. But i am 100% certain it is exactly what you want to achieve.

I too used "https://github.com/RickRedSix/BLE4.0-iOS-Swift-Demo" for reference.

Hope this helps you solve your problem. Let me know if you have any doubts.

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import CoreBluetooth

class BLEDeviceTableViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate {

private var myTableView: UITableView!

var manager : CBCentralManager!
var myBluetoothPeripheral = [CBPeripheral]()
var myCharacteristic : CBCharacteristic!

var isMyPeripheralConected = false

var peripheralNames = [String]()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let displayWidth: CGFloat = self.view.frame.width

    manager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)

    myTableView = UITableView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 135, width: displayWidth, height: (self.view.frame.height-(self.view.frame.height/3))-10))
    myTableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "MyCell")
    myTableView.dataSource = self
    myTableView.delegate = self
    self.view.addSubview(myTableView)

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {

    var msg = ""

    switch central.state {

    case .poweredOff:
        msg = "Bluetooth is Off"
    case .poweredOn:
        msg = "Bluetooth is On"
        manager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil, options: nil)
    case .unsupported:
        msg = "Not Supported"
    default:
        msg = ""

    }

    print("STATE: " + msg)

}

func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {



    peripheralNames.append(peripheral.name ?? "Unknown Device")
    print(peripheral)


    self.myBluetoothPeripheral.append(peripheral)      //save peripheral

    print(peripheralNames)
    myTableView.reloadData()
}

func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
    print("Connected to \(peripheral.name ?? "Uknown Device")")
    availableDeviceLabel.text = "Connected to \(peripheral.name ?? "Uknown Device")"
    isMyPeripheralConected = true //when connected change to true
    peripheral.delegate = self
    peripheral.discoverServices(nil)
}

func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDisconnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, error: Error?) {
    isMyPeripheralConected = false //and to falso when disconnected
}


func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: Error?) {

    print("Services:\(String(describing: peripheral.services)) and error\(String(describing: error))")
    if let services = peripheral.services {
        for service in services {
            peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(nil, for: service)
        }
    }

}

func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService, error: Error?) {


    print("peripheral:\(peripheral) and service:\(service)")

    for characteristic in service.characteristics!
    {
        peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, for: characteristic)
    }

}

func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {

    let readValue = characteristic.value

    print("Response from BLE Device: \(readValue)")

}

//if you want to send an string you can use this function.
func writeValue() {

    if isMyPeripheralConected {

        //check if myPeripheral is connected to send data

        //let dataToSend: Data = "Hello World!".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!

        //myBluetoothPeripheral.writeValue(dataToSend, for: myCharacteristic, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.withoutResponse)    //Writing the data to the peripheral

    } else {
        print("Not connected")
    }
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    //let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: tag, inSection: 0)
    //let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! gpsSettingsCustomCell!
    //print(cell?.cellLabel.text ?? "")

    self.myBluetoothPeripheral[indexPath.row].delegate = self

    manager.stopScan()                          //stop scanning for peripherals
    manager.connect(myBluetoothPeripheral[indexPath.row], options: nil)

    myTableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 60
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return peripheralNames.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = gpsSettingsCustomCell(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 60), title: "Hello")
    cell.cellLabel.text = peripheralNames[indexPath.row]
    cell.cellLabel2.text = "Bluetooth Device"
    return cell

}

class BLEDeviceCustomCell: UITableViewCell {
//var cellButton: UIButton!
var cellLabel: UILabel!
var cellLabel2: UILabel!

init(frame: CGRect, title: String) {
    super.init(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    //super.init(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")

    cellLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: self.frame.width, height: 20))
    cellLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Titillium-Regular", size: 14.0)
    //cellLabel= UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(self.frame.width - 100, 10, 100.0, 40))
    cellLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
    //cellLabel.font = //set font here

    cellLabel2 = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 30, width: self.frame.width, height: 20))
    cellLabel2.font = UIFont(name: "Titillium-Regular", size: 14.0)
    cellLabel2.textColor = UIColor.gray
    //cellButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(5, 5, 50, 30))
    //cellButton.setTitle(title, forState: UIControlState.Normal)

    addSubview(cellLabel)
    addSubview(cellLabel2)
    //addSubview(cellButton)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response Cedan. I'm getting errors when running this, probably because the code doesn't complement the rest of the code. Was this the only part you changed for your project Cedan from Rick's code? If you have the xcode files uploaded somewhere then that be much appreciated.

Comment: @Campbell ok give an hour or so and I will share a Xcode project that implements this code without errors. The above code I had just copied from my project so as u said it wouldn’t work because it doesn’t connect with the rest of the code. So I will share a project soon.

Comment: @Campbell so i have created a test project for you. You can find it at this link. 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/0onurtjd723ynn2/BLE%20Test.zip?dl=0
Make sure you follow these steps in order for it to work.
1. Make sure you run this on a real device.
2. For the app to find a BLE device, download and install `LightBlue Explorer` on another device and create a virtual peripheral so that the device running the code can scan and find this test bluetooth peripheral that you created. Or you could also use any other BLE device like a fitness band or so.
Let me know if it works.

Comment: I understand the idea and it's really cool. My problem is that I want the app to connect to a BLE module, so Lightblue explorer can't be downloaded on it. Thanks so much for your help though it meant a lot.

Comment: @Campbell what sort of BLE Module are you using ? When you run the project that i sent you, does it display the name of the BLE module ???

Comment: Is there any reason why we have to call stopScan(); before connect(); when we did select a row? Will it make the connecting fail or something?

Comment: The reason it's there is because this is just a test project to show you how to connect to different devices in a list. So when you are connecting to a new device I just stop the scan. It's not compulsory to add it in a real time project.

Answer (score 0):

That message means that you should power on the bluetooth, and then search for the devices.  Something like:

```
func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
    switch central.state {
    case .unknown:
        print("Unknown")
    case .resetting:
        print("Resetting")
    case .unsupported:
        print("Unsupported")
    case .unauthorized:
        print("Unauthorized")
    case .poweredOff:
        print("Powered Off")
        central.stopScan()
    case .poweredOn:
        print("Powered On")
        central.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil, options: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried adding these cases to my project but I'm still getting the same error as before. I've tried setting the scan to all available peripherals but it's still not working.