# Using coreBluetooth in iOS, Can we create multiple peripheral connection and get services from both peripheral in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, ios-bluetooth

I like to connect two Bluetooth devices and get the data in my application. Connection with multiple devices is successful. I like to get the services from both devices parallel. If anyone has worked with multiple connections, help me with this.

Comment: "but communication is possible with only one device" How so? A Central should be able to connect to multiple peripheral (if allowed by code).

Comment: @Larme I am getting the services from the last connected peripheral, not both peripherals.

Comment: You need to share code. It's simply, but I guess you don't keep a reference on BOTH devices, like `self.periperhal1 = peripheral` and at other point `self.peripheral2 = peripheral` in `didDiscoverPeripheral`, and then in each method, check `peripheral == self.peripheral1`, etc.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53526621/scanning-ble-peripheral-and-connecting-to-it/53527093

Comment: Very much possible. But since you didn’t share any code it is impossible to help you