# Cannot connect to multiple BLE peripherals at the same time in IOS

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth

I want to connect to multiple peripherals at the same time. I have an array of peripherals which I populated already from tableview cells.

```
private(set) var connectingPeripherals = [String: CBPeripheral]()
```

Then inside a function I am populating this property.

```
self.connectingPeripherals[peripheral.identifier.uuidString] = peripheral
```

Now when I loop through the peripherals for connection, only the first peripheral in the list gets connected.

```
for (_,v) in connectingPeripherals
            {
                if v.state == .disconnected
                {
                    self.connectPeripheral(v, onFinish: {_ in})
                }
            }
```

My connect peripheral function is this

```
func connectPeripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral)
    {
        print("Bluetooth Manager --> connectPeripheral")
     
        if !isConnecting
        {
            isConnecting = true
            _manager?.connect(peripheral, options: [CBConnectPeripheralOptionNotifyOnConnectionKey: true])
            timeoutMonitor = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(self.connectionTimeout(_:)), userInfo: peripheral, repeats: false)
        }
    }
```

PS - I have already went through this SO post to solve the task..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38807798/how-to-connect-to-2-or-more-peripherals-while-receiving-data-from-all-at-once-us

Comment: How do you brain the peripheral instances that you are putting in the dictionary? The other problem i see is that you are creating multiple timers, but each call the same method, there is no way to identify in that method *which connection* timed out and most importantly you can't cancel the timers when you get a successful connection.

Comment: The peripherals are being populated in the dictionary correctly...when the view loads..Also I am invalidating the timer in the didConnect function..

Comment: But you aren't invalidating *all* the times.  For example, if you had 4 peripherals, you will call `connectPeripheral` 4 times and create 4 timers, each overwriting the last timer stored in the property.  When a peripheral connects you will invalidate that timer, but the other 3 will still be running.  Regardless, it is possible to connect to multiple peripherals concurrently, so the problem is in your code and in code not shown, but the code that you have shown doesn't handle concurrency correctly